# Handler postDelayed executes few times

Tags: java, android

I have a SeekBar on my UI. I want to report its value in a TextView, when I change its position. In this TextView, I also want to provide an information, how long is the position still (in seconds). I thought, the run method in a Runnable, will run only once, but it runs couple of times per one postDelayed execution. No matter the delay is 1s or 10s long. How to force it to run only one time? Should I make a thread?

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    y=0;
    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
           myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
           progressIndicator.setText("Covered: " + progressX.getProgress() + "/" + progressX.getMax() + " position is still for " + y + " seconds");
                    y+=1;
           }
    },1000);
}
```

EDIT:
removeCallbacks helped a bit. The code works correctly, but only on the first progressChange now, I'll try to figure it out tomorrow.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  y=0;
  myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run(){
           myHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
           y+=1;
           progressIndicator.setText("Covered: " + progressX.getProgress() + "/" + progressX.getMax() + " position is still for " + y + " seconds");
           myHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
           }
   },5000);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that, the every event *onProgressChanged* ran new runnable simultaneously. Placing *myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable)* inside *run* method, gave a bit positive effect and it was the only place where it worked "correctly". In effect, *y* was incremented very fast, by a value of delta of our previous and current position of seekbar (accumulation of *postDelayed* methods), and after that, it was incremented by 1 every second. *removeCallbacks* killed previous *postDelayed* actions.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            y=0;
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    ...
                    y+=1;
                    runnable=this;
                    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                    }
            },1000);
```

However, and **this is the solution**, placing *myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)* inside *onProgressChanged* helped.
I attach the code for better understanding. **The TextView** *progressIndicator* **shows, how long do you stay at current position of a seekbar (in seconds).**

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            y=0;
            progressIndicator.setText("Covered: " + progressX.getProgress() + "/" +
                    progressX.getMax());
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    y+=1;
                    progressIndicator.setText("Covered: " + progressX.getProgress() + "/" +
                            progressX.getMax() + " position is still for " + y + " seconds");
                    runnable=this;
                    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

                }
            },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically using a pattern to repeat the `Runnable` forever. Inside your `Runnable`, you have a call to `mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`. The `this` in this context is the `new Runnable` that you created initially. That means that the `Runnable` will schedule another run one second later each time it executes.

If you only want it to run once, you should just remove the `mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` line.

You should also ensure that you call `mHandler.removeCallbacks(null)` in `onDestroy()` to ensure you don't cause a memory leak since your `Runnable` will hold a reference to your `Activity` through the `TextView` reference.

Comment: The patterns task is to run forever. But every 1s (or for example 10s) period, I want to increment the y only once (by value 1 or 10, to show proper value of seconds, the seek bar in in the same position.

This is only a practice. Finally, I want to send one message per some ammount of time to a microcontroller, to set a value of PWM to control speed of a DC motor. I want for example one and only one message per second.

Answer (score 0):

`onProgressChanged` is called a couple of times when the seekbar is moved, that means that you have several pending `postDelayed()`

To solve it, each time you call `postDelayed()` you should call first `removeCallbacks()` that ensures only one pending `postDelayed()` will be active

But you will need to create the Runnable and the Handler instances in the class fields and not on the `onProgressChanged` body

Something like this:

```
     private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
     private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something //
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
                myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
            }
        };




     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
         // do something //
         myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
         myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
}
```